# Window fading in causing quick white flash of window contents before fading in happens

Tags: wpf, animation

I want a WPF window to fade in when in opens.  I set the following trigger for the window load:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="FormFade">
                <DoubleAnimation  Name="FormFadeAnimation"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Window"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:5"
                                        AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                     />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

The issue is that when the window first loads, it shows all white for the content then disappears and then the window contents fades in as expected.  How can I get rid of the flash of white that happens at the beginning?  I have even set the background of the window to black but it still flashes white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is caused by processing in your Window.Loaded handler.  The Animation will not run until your Window.Loaded handler finishes executing.  I was able to recreate your problem by doing this:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The Screen will be White for 1000ms because the animation will not run until the Sleep ends.  If you take away the Thread.Sleep() call, the result is what you would expect.  My guess is you are doing quite a bit of work in your Loaded handler and the animation is being delayed.

By the way here is the MainWindow.xaml, pretty much the same to what you have:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="Window">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Name="FormFade">
                    <DoubleAnimation  Name="FormFadeAnimation"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Window"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:5"
                                        AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                     />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>asdf</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I removed all processing in the handler and the flashing of the white window still appears.  It is quick but still happens.

Comment: Well the white flashing does not happen for me.  Perhaps you should create a new WPF Forms project with just one window and the fading effect like I have done above, just to make sure the problem is not due to something weird with your development environment as opposed to coding logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Window.Opacity` to 0 to begin with, in the `<Window>` tag.

EDIT: @H.B is absolutely right.  The window needs to have `AllowsTransparency=true` also, and for that, the window chrome needs to be off (`WindowStyle=None`).  I reproduced your problem, then did this to make it work the way you want it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
        Opacity="0" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Name="FormFade">
                    <DoubleAnimation  Name="FormFadeAnimation"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
                                        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:5"
                                        AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                     />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Still didn't make a difference.  It is odd too because I have code in the Window_Loaded event handler and if I set a breakpoint there, the window is shown all white for the contents.  Even the background of black is not set yet.  The value of Opacity is 0 and the Background is Black but the window contents is all white.

Comment: That much doesn't surprise me, but it does surprise me that the window shows at all if you set the opacity to 0 in the XAML.

Comment: @ChrisShain: That is not surprising as by default `AllowsTransparency` is `false`, so transparancy results in black.

Answer (score 0):

##### Problem

This happened to me also. The provided answers did not help because I wanted to "re-show" the same window.  If you call `.Hide()` on your window, then you call `.Show()`, the first frame will be full opacity.

##### Solution

My best guess is that the window is re-rendering on `.Show()` however it was last displayed. I could be wrong. But the fix worked. Essentially we need to make sure we set our `Opacity=0` right before `Hide()`ing the window.

Use code-behind, because no permutation of xaml storyboarding would work for me. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Create an extension method to keep things pretty:

```
public static class Animate
{
    public static void fade_in(this Window window)
    {
        fade(window, () => { });
    }

    public static void fade_out(this Window window, Action on_finish)
    {
        fade(window, on_finish, start:1, end:0);
    }

    static void fade(this Window window, Action on_finish, double duration_in_seconds = 0.15, double start = 0, double end = 1)
    {
        // This will all be optimized by the compiler.
        int frames_per_second = 60;  // Give us a smooth animation
        double change = end - start;
        double change_per_second = change / duration_in_seconds;
        double change_per_frame = change_per_second / frames_per_second;
        double number_of_frames = duration_in_seconds * frames_per_second;

        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_frames; i++)
            {
                var proportion_complete = (i+1) / number_of_frames;
                window.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { window.Opacity = Lerp(start, end, proportion_complete); });

                Thread.Sleep(1000 / 60);  // Sleep 1/60'th of a second.  Likely the monitor's refresh rate.
            }

            on_finish();
        });
    }

    static double Lerp(double first, double second, double by)
    {
        return first + (second - first) * by;
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to hide your popup window:

```
popup_window.fade_out(() => popup_window.Dispatcher.Invoke(popup_window.Hide));
```

Then show it with this:

```
popup_window.fade_in();
popup_window.Show();
```

##### Pitfalls

You probably want to set `Opacity = 0` in XAML, if your window is meant to start transparent, [like Chris Shain suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9203025/10871073).

Also, keep the animation speed pretty quick, so you don't have to worry about the fade_in/fade_out animations overlapping.